# Why the tangent bundle is Hausdorff?

Tags: differential-geometry

I was reading the lemma 4.1 in "J.M.Lee - Introduction to smooth manifolds" which says that given a smooth $n$-manifold $M$, then  the tangent bundle $TM$ is a smooth $2n$-manifold.

If $\pi: TM\rightarrow M$ is the natural projection, given an atlas $\mathcal A=\{(U_i,\phi_i)\}$ on $M$, we can define a collection of sets $\{\pi^{-1}(U_i)\}$ and a collection of functions $\widetilde\phi_i:\pi^{-1}(U_i)\rightarrow \mathbb R^{2n}$ which both satisfy the lemma 1.23 namely the construcion lemma for smooth manifolds.

More precisely, on $TM$ is   defined the topology having as base the set
$$B=\{\widetilde{\phi_i}^{-1}(V)\; \textrm{for all $i$}:\,\textrm{$V$ is open in $\mathbb R^{2n}$}\}$$

I have some problems to prove that $TM$ is Hausdorff: clearly it is enough to show that given two distinct point $P=(p,X),Q=(q,Y)\in TM$, either then exist some $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ containing both $P$ and $Q$ or there exist disjoint sets $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ and $\pi^{-1}(U_j)$ with $P\in \pi^{-1}(U_i)$ and $Q\in \pi^{-1}(U_j)$. If $P$ and $Q$ lie in the same fiber of $\pi$ it is all clear, but if they lie in different fibres than $\pi (P)=p\neq q=\pi(Q)$ and J.M. Lee says

> **there exist disjoint smooth coordinate domains $U,V$ for $M$ such that $p\in U$ and $q\in V$**

Why is this true? $M$ is Hausdorff, but open sets of $M$ are not the smooth coordinate domains (the latter form a subset of the former)!

Comment: Given disjoint open sets $U, V \subset M$ with $p \in U$ and $q \in V$, you can find subsets $U' \subseteq U$ and $V' \subseteq V$ which are smooth coordinate domains for $M$ and $p \in U'$, $q \in V'$. Let $U$ and $V$ be such open sets and let $X$ be a coordinate neighbourhood for $p$ and $Y$ a coordinate neighbourhood for $q$. Then set $U' = U \cap X$ and $V' = V \cap Y$.

Comment: OP could be confused because Lee's proof (of proposition 3.18 on tangent bundle) first says "Choose a countable cover $\{U_i\}$ of $M$ by smooth coordinate domains..." and establish (i) to (iv) of lemma 1.23 before checking Hausdorff. The answers below involve coordinate domains that are not necessarily in the countable cover. Thus, the right way to fix this is to allow all smooth coordinate domains but when checking (iv), realise that a countable cover exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let me fix some terminology (taken from Lee's book).

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold. A *coordinate chart* on $M$ is a pair $(U, \varphi)$ where $U$ is an open subset of $M$ and $\varphi : U \to \tilde{U}$ is a homeomorphism from $U$ to an open subset $\tilde{U} = \varphi(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. The set $U$ is called a *coordinate domain*.

Now to the situation at hand. As $M$ is Hausdorff, and $p \neq q$, there are disjoint open sets $U, V \subset M$ with $p \in U$ and $q \in V$. As you note, there is no guarantee that $U$ and $V$ will be coordinate domains. While that is true, we can take them to be coordinate domains without loss of generality. Let $(X, \varphi)$, $(Y, \psi)$ be charts (i.e. $X, Y$ are coordinate domains) with $p \in X$ and $q \in Y$ (note, we do not require $X$ and $Y$ to be disjoint).

**Claim:** The sets $U' = U\cap X$, $V' = V\cap Y$ are coordinate domains with $p \in U'$ and $q \in V'$.

As $U'$ and $V'$ are open, and the restriction of a homeomorphism to an open subset is a homeomorphism, $(U', \varphi|_{U'})$ and $(V', \psi|_{V'})$ are charts; that is, $U'$ and $V'$ are coordinate domains. As $p \in U$ and $p\in X$, $p \in U'$; likewise, as $q \in V$ and $q \in Y$, $q \in V'$.

So, without loss of generality, we can take $U$ and $V$ to be coordinate domains (if they aren't, pass to subsets $U' \subseteq U$, $V' \subseteq V$ which are, and call these sets $U$ and $V$ respectively).

Answer (score 1):

$TX= \{(p,v) : p \in X, v \in T_{p}X \}$ since $X$ and $T_{p}(X)$ are connected Hausdorff spaces ( $T_{p}(X)$ is a subspace of manifold $X$ ) Hence $TX$ is a connected Hausdorff space